# Feign client concurrency issue

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, hystrix, spring-cloud-feign, feign

I have setup `Spring Cloud (Camden.SR7)` with `Eureka (1.3.5.RELEASE)`, `Config server` and several `Spring Boot (1.5.7.RELEASE)` microservices. Communication between microservices is performed with `Feign` client (`Hystrix` is disabled). Although this works correctly during development, I noticed that under high traffic when multiple simultaneous calls are made between the same microservices, then the threads become deadlocked and no responses are received. This seems as if Feign client does not behave correctly in multi-thread.

I currently use the `SEMAPHORE` isolation strategy. I also tried changing the isolation strategy to `THREAD` and specifying a thread pool, but in this case I got 403 error for all my calls. I also experimented with `feign-httpclient` as an alternative and although this seemed to improve the situation, it required hardcoded URLs instead of retrieving them from `Eureka`, so I did not proceed with this solution.

Any ideas how to fix this? My code is as follows

bootstrap.yml:

```
hystrix:
  command:
    default:
      execution:
        isolation:
          strategy: SEMAPHORE
          semaphore:
            maxConcurrentRequests: 100000 # basically 'unlimited'
        timeout:
          enabled: false
      circuitBreaker:
        enabled: false
      fallback:
        enabled:  false
ribbon:
  ConnectTimeout: 180000
  ReadTimeout: 180000
```

FeignClientConfiguration:

```
@Configuration
public class FeignClientConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public Retryer retryer() {
        return new Retryer() {
            @Override
            public void continueOrPropagate(RetryableException e) {
                throw e;
            }
            @Override
            public Retryer clone() {
                return this;
            }
        };
    }
    @Bean
    public RequestInterceptor requestTokenBearerInterceptor() {
        return requestTemplate -> {
     requestTemplate.header("Authorization",JWTUtil.getAuthorizationToken());
        };
    }
```

FeignClient:

```
@FeignClient(name = "audit-log-service", configuration = FeignClientConfiguration.class)
public interface AuditLogFeignClient {
    @RequestMapping("/audit-log-ms/audit/save")
    void saveEntityToDatabase(@RequestBody Object object);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add in yml configuration file the property sharedSecurityContext: true.
This will share the Security context of main thread to the one used by the Hystrix command when you use isolation strategy `THREAD`

.
 See [here](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-netflix/1.2.0.RELEASE/#_propagating_the_security_context_or_using_spring_scopes).

Comment: Thank you, this seems to work. By adding this property I no longer get the 403 errors with THREAD strategy and this seems to solve the concurrency issue.